# Complicated Report Requires SQL Temp File C# Returns No Rows

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

Here is the problem.  I have to write a long, hella complicated report.  I don't think I can do it using only C# so I thought the best thing was a temporary SQL table.  So I wrote this code and I always get no rows and I know there is data in the table.

```
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader reader;

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * INTO ##temp FROM Customers";
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        connection.Open();

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        { MessageBox.Show("ROWS"); }
        else
        { MessageBox.Show("NO ROWS"); }

        connection.Close();
```

So I thought, maybe I need another reader to SELECT * FROM ##TEMP but it always crashes telling me that my reader is already open (I used reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();).  Please help.

Comment: What does "crash" mean? If you get no rows then there are no resultset rows.. since you select *into* a temp table, I've no idea why result rows would even be expected. It is clearly not the behavior to emit a resultset when selecting *into* a temp table, as can be evidenced by running the query in SSMS.

Comment: Okay - you are right.  It was crashing when I started the post but I fixed it.  I changed the title to the question.  Do you think you can help with my problem?  How do I get the rows from the temp file?

Comment: I rolled back your edit. If you found a solution that you think will benefit future readers, then use the space below captioned *Your Answer* and put it there. It's perfectly acceptable to [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from ##temp";
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

First run ExecuteNonQuery, then change the command then run ExecuteReader

Answer (score 0):

Your question fails to justify the use of a temporary table.  There really is no reason for you not to simply read the data directly from the actual table (unless your question omitted important and relevant details).

Also, it's a good idea to get in the habit of disposing the db objects with `using` blocks to clean up properly even in the event of exceptions.

Here is what the code could look like:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers", connection))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ROWS");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("NO ROWS");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it's really interesting that you think I shouldn't use a temporary table.  Here is the scope of the report:  it will be copied into a workbook with about 10 worksheets - each worksheet containing about 1000 rows and about 30 columns.  I thought that was way too much data to keep in memory but I am not experienced in this so I would very much like your opinion on whether it is or not and why.